# What does netmask mean for a Public IP?

Tags: linux, networking, vps, digital-ocean

I understand how netmasks work - they are used to extract the network portion of an IP address and therefore used to define a network.

When I create a new droplet on digitalocean, I get a Public IP for this droplet which can be used to access the server. But I do not understand what the netmask I get means for my Public IP..

My confusions are:

1. I only rented ONE computer from digitalocean, not a network, in which case should the netmask just be 255.255.255.255???
2. When users view stuff on my site or when I login my droplet using ssh , we only need to enter the Public IP address, not the netmask. And provided that packets are transferred by making 'hop' between routers. If a netmask is not provided, how do routers decide what the next hop is (it's need th netmask to look up the routing table).

Thank you for looking at the question. I've been thinking about this for a few days.. but still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routers route based on the destination IP address in the IP packet header. This IP address has no mask. A router will look in its routing table to find the prefix which matches the closest to the IP address, and it will send the packet in the direction from the routing table entry.

A default prefix (`0.0.0.0/0`) may be configured in a router, and that will match any IP address, but the mask length (`0`) will be the shortest match, so the default prefix will be used as a last resort.

If a router finds no prefix which matches the IP address, or a default prefix, the packet will be discarded.

Comment: Ron, thanks for the answer, so that case why does a public IP need a net mask? Isn't a public IP unique already?

Comment: On any particular host, you have an IP address and network mask so that the host knows when destinations are not on the same network so that the frames containing the packets can be sent to the configured gateway's MAC address instead of looking on the same network for a MAC address associated with the IP address.